# How to deal with repeatable similar html content

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

On my website, I have a lot of similar content that gets repeated within the same page. Looks like this:

```html
<a href="link1"><img src="path1" alt="name1"></a>
<a href="link2"><img src="path2" alt="name2"></a>
<a href="link3"><img src="path3" alt="name3"></a>
<a href="link4"><img src="path4" alt="name4"></a>
...
```

I am thinking of using a loop to deal with the repeating content but to do that I need to save the different parts of the repeating content into an array. Using PHP it would look like that:

```html
<?php
    $images = [
        ["href" => "link1", 
         "src" => "path1", 
         "alt" => "name1"
        ],
        ["href" => "link2", 
         "src" => "path2", 
         "alt" => "name2"
        ],
        ...
?>
```

I would like to ask what the best practice for storing the content would be so that the performance of the website would be as good as possible. Is sticking to PHP the best, or maybe I should use a JSON file or something else?

Note: I don't want to use a database.

Comment: Not clear what's the problem here. If you can store data in array - store it there. If you need to store data between requests - files, databases, sessions.

Comment: Best to keep as much load off the client as possible, within reason, I think - if you can send the repetitive raw HTML, it'll be compressed when sent (so don't worry about bandwidth).

Comment: I am asking what the best practice is for storing elements that would be looped through. I could do it with PHP but it could be done with JSON as well and probably other methods as well. Which is regarded as the best one?

Comment: The amount of data here is so tiny, in terms of performance it will not matter one bit. Go read up on why this kind of premature micro-optimization doesn’t make much sense, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding

Comment: There are ~200 anchors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with fixed number link and image path then using a JSON file or hardcoding into the source is ok. But if your content is dynamic then you can use a database like MySql for storing your links and image paths and loop through it using PHP for generating HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through.

```
<a href="link1"><img src="path1" alt="name1"></a>
<a href="link2"><img src="path2" alt="name2"></a>
<a href="link3"><img src="path3" alt="name3"></a>
<a href="link4"><img src="path4" alt="name4"></a>
```

## Array:

```
$images = [
   0 => [
      'link' => 'https://google.com/',
      'image' => 'assets/image/0.png',
      'name' => 'name 0'
   ],
   1 => [
      'link' => 'https://google.com/',
      'image' => 'assets/image/1.png',
      'name' => 'name 1'
   ],
   2 => [
      'link' => 'https://google.com/',
      'image' => 'assets/image/2.png',
      'name' => 'name 2'
   ],
   3 => [
      'link' => 'https://google.com/',
      'image' => 'assets/image/3.png',
      'name' => 'name 3'
   ],
];

foreach($images as $image) { //Then loop through the array and echo it individually
   echo '
      <a href="'.$image['link'].'">
         <img src="'.$image['link'].'" alt="'.$image['name'].'">
      </a>
   ';
}
```

## Result:

```
<a href="https://google.com/"><img src="assets/image/0.png" alt="name 0"></a>
<a href="https://google.com/"><img src="assets/image/1.png" alt="name 1"></a>
<a href="https://google.com/"><img src="assets/image/2.png" alt="name 2"></a>
<a href="https://google.com/"><img src="assets/image/3.png" alt="name 3"></a>
```